# Pass array to label with Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

i'm trying to pass the textfield data into an array and then pass it from ViewController2 to ViewController. In the new view controller, it will print out all elements in the array.

The error i get is in ViewController2.m:No visible @interface for 'UItextField' declared the selector 'componentsSeparatedByString:'

I've checked every connection and they are correct.

ViewController2.h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *HomePlayers;
```

ViewController2.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SaveData"]) {
        ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSArray *homePlayersText = [HomePlayers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        vc.HomePlayersString = homePlayersText;
     }

 }
```

ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *HomePlayersLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *HomePlayersString;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize HomePlayersString, HomePlayersLabel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to separate the components of the label you first need to get the string value. As your example.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SaveData"]) {
    ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSString * stringValue = self.HomePlayers.text;
    NSArray *homePlayersText = [stringValue componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    vc.HomePlayersString = homePlayersText;
 }
```

}

Also I recommend you to write your class attributes with a lower-cap at the beggining as It's one of apple's suggestions. Classes with uppercase as "TestClass", attributes with lowercase as "randomClass".

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to access the `text` property of the `UITextField`:

```
NSArray *homePlayersText = [HomePlayers.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Other remarks:

- The convention for instance variables is to use names starting
  with a lower-case letter, e.g. `homePlayers`.
- The `HomePlayersString` property should be declared strong, not weak,
  as pointed out by @rdelmar. Otherwise `vc.HomePlayersString` will be `nil`
  shortly after assigning the value.
- The `@synthesize` statement is not needed anymore with the current compiler versions.

Comment: Also, the array HomePlayersString, should be typed strong, not weak.